# Using the VLC plugin of a web page, how do I keep the last frame of the previous video while switching video?

Tags: html, vlc, live-streaming

I am doing a live website.

I use the VLC plugin to play the video stream.

When I switch between different videos, the VLC logo will always appear in the middle of the two videos.

I hope this logo screen will be replaced by the last frame of the previous video.

How should I set up the VLC plugin?

Comment: I doubt you get this sort of control over the plugin.  Maybe just replace the whole instance of the plugin with a new one when you swap videos?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use VLC. Use the video tag, or MSE.

Comment: I need to play some multicast videos, such as `udp://@224.1.2.3:12345`. Can MSE do it?

Comment: No MSE can’t, and VLC Will do what ever VLC does. If your doing something that non standard, you are basically at the whims of the tools available. But VLC is open source. Feel free to modify it.